# How do I get this ARM program to stop seg faulting?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to create a program that calculates the string length of the string that I have to scan in.  This is what I have, but it seg faults at `ldrb r1, [r1]`.  I'm trying to increment the address to reach the next character within the string.

```
.section .data

.balign 4
scan_pattern: .asciz "%s"

.balign 4
string: .word 50

.balign 4
null_char: .byte '\0'

.balign 4
result: .asciz "%d"

.section .text
.global main

main:
    ldr r0, =scan_pattern
    ldr r1, =string
    bl scanf

    mov r0, #0
    ldrb r1, [r1]
    ldr r2, =null_char
    ldrb r2, [r2]
    bl count
count:
    cmp r1, r2
    bne incr
    bl end_pro

incr:
    add r1, r1, #1
    add r0, r0, #1
    bl count

end_pro:
    ldr r1, [r0]
    ldr r0, =result
    ldr r1, [r1]
    bl printf

    mov r0, $0
    bl fflush

    nop             @no operation
    mov r7, $1      @exit syscall
    svc $0          @wake kernel
    .end
```

Comment: Are you sure you know what the directive `.word` means?

Comment: It's because R1 isn't preserved by the call to `scanf`. Your code has a number of other mistakes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r1` can/will be clobbered by `sscanf`; you need to restore it after the call. E.g.

```
ldr r4, =string
mov r1, r4
bl sscanf
...
ldr r1, [r4]      ; formerly: ldr r1, [r1]
```

But on first glance, there seem to be more problems in the program (the second `ldr r1, [r1]` crashes probably too, the `bl` are not directly wrong but a simple `b` jump would be more usual, you do not iterate over the string, ...).

I suggest to write your algorithm in C, compile it and look with 'objdump -d' at the binary to get an idea how to solve it...

EDIT:

A simple and untested `strlen()` implementation could look like

```
@ size_t xstrlen(char const *s)
xstrlen:
    mov  r3, r0           @ char const *orig = s
1:
    ldrb r1, [r0], #1     @ char c = *s++;
    cmp  r1, #0           @ if (c != 0)
    bne  1b               @       goto 1;

    sub  r0, r0, r3       @ return s - orig - 1
    sub  r0, #1
    bx   lr
```

Call it like

```
main:
    ldr r0, =scan_pattern
    ldr r1, =string
    bl  scanf

    ldr r0, =string
    bl  xstrlen

    mov r1, r0
    ldr r0, =result
    bl  printf
```

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know if you want to help, but how do I do a compare to tell if it's at the end of the string?  Because, what I have just gets stuck.